# How to convert this Cypher query to Neo4jClient?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Using this query in Neo4j I get the node:

```
match (a)
where id(a)=0 
return a;
```

How do I retrieve a node by its `Neo4j` ID, *not* a `POCO` ID in `Neo4jClient`

Comment: Did you looked for it somewhere? your query is really basic and only gets a node by its ID. I'm pretty sure it's in the base documentation of Neo4jClient... https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#get-all-users-by-label

Comment: the Id in User Class doesn't  return Id the node in neo4j DB.is different id .

Comment: The `id` used here is the `Neo4j` ID, not a POCO ID, so it's not covered *explicitly* in the docs :/

Answer (score 1):

The `id` you're using gets the neo4j ID, not an ID of your own class. You can get the node via:

```
client.Match("(a)")
    .Where("id(a) = {idParam}")
    .WithParam("idParam", 0)
    .Return(a => a.As<Node<string>>())
```